# Fill textbox with database date using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have dates and amount data. I want to fill this data to the right text input. As you see in the jsFiddle some months have data, and some months don't have data.

In my example below I generate the inputs manually, but I need need to create them with a `for`-loop, because I must generate textboxes first date month to today month.

What is the easy way for doing this?

jsFiddle:

```js
// Date format dd MM yyyy
var salaryData = [['date':'1.1.2015','amount':'100'],['date':'5.3.2015','amount':'105'],['date':'8.4.2015','amount':'1900'],['date':'15.6.2015','amount':'1005']]
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Salary days</h1>
    <ul>
        <li> Amount / Date  </li>
        <li>
            January 2015 <input type="text" name="janPrice" /><input type="text" name="date" />
        </li>
        <li>
            February 2015 <input type="text" name="janPrice" /><input type="text" name="date" />
        </li>
           <li>
            March 2015 <input type="text" name="janPrice" /><input type="text" name="date" />
        </li>
           <li>
            April 2015 <input type="text" name="janPrice" /><input type="text" name="date" />
        </li>
          <li>
            Haziran 2015 <input type="text" name="janPrice" /><input type="text" name="date" />
        </li>
            <li>
            June 2015 <input type="text" name="janPrice" /><input type="text" name="date" />
        </li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/unqq5vsk/)

Comment: Please try to explain again, in different words, what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the JavaScript code for you. I'm not sure, whether this solves your problem. I hope that I understand you right ;)

```
// Date format dd MM yyyy
var salaryData = [
    {
        'date': '1.1.2015',
        'amount':'101'
    },
    {
        'date': '1.2.2015',
        'amount':'102'
    },
    {
        'date': '1.3.2015',
        'amount':'103'
    },
    {
        'date': '1.4.2015',
        'amount':'104'
    } 
];

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");

var month = salaryData.map( function( salary ) {
    return filterMonth( salary.date );
});

var year = salaryData.map( function( salary ) {
    return filterYear( salary.date );
});


salaryData.forEach( function( salary, index ){
    var listEntry = "<li>"+ month[index] +" "+ year[index] +" <input type='text' name='janPrice' value='"+ salaryData[index].amount +"' /><input type='text' name='year' value='"+ salaryData[index].date +"' />";
    list[0].innerHTML += listEntry;
});

function filterMonth( strDate ) {
    var dateParts = strDate.split(".");
    var d = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    return monthNames[d.getMonth()];
}

function filterYear( strDate ) {
    var dateParts = strDate.split(".");
    var d = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    return d.getFullYear();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unqq5vsk/2/

First, I correct your data container. Then I read the month and year property from your array object and generate the HTML to output the files.

Comment: thx but Even if the date is not in data i want see empty input.For example First time user dont write date and amount for october but when update user can write amount for october.

Comment: ok, but why you dont control the amount of fields with the salaryData object? you can let the field "amount" to be an empty string (amount=""). And if the date field isn't given, which months should be displayed. Months from the current year?

Answer (score -1):

Your data-format for `salaryData` is invalid for javascript. You want nested objects inside your wrapping array, as such: `[{id: val}, {id: val}]`. This is because there are no associative array's in javascript (everything is an object).

Once this is fixed, there is the problem that your sample data is inconsistent with your question: *Because I must generate textboxes first date month to today month*. It is currently May, yet your data has month 6 (assuming your month's in your data are 1-based), so I dropped that data-point from your `salaryData` as we can't see in the future.

Now we have a correct example dataset.

Finally you commented: *Even if the date is not in data I want see empty input.*
So here goes the updated *example* version (generating textarea's from Jan to current month and populating them with data where available):

```js
var salaryData = [{'date':'1.1.2015','amount':'100'},{'date':'5.3.2015','amount':'105'},{'date':'8.4.2015','amount':'1900'}];

console.log(
  demo(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0], salaryData).innerHTML
);

function demo(par, data){
  var a = document.createElement('li')
  ,   b = document.createElement('input')
  ,  ul = document.createElement('ul')
  ,  ml = [ 'January','February','March','April','May','June','July'
          , 'August','September','October','November','December'
          ]
  ,  ms = [ 'jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul'
          , 'aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'
          ]
  ,   t = new Date()
  ,   y = t.getFullYear()
  ,   m = t.getMonth()+1
  ,   i
  ; //end local vars

  b.setAttribute('type','text');
  ul.appendChild(a.cloneNode(false)).innerHTML = 'Amount / Date';

  // build inputs in DOM
  for(i = 0; i<m; ++i) {
    t = a.cloneNode(false);
    t.innerHTML = ml[i] + ' ' + y + ' ';
    t.appendChild(b.cloneNode(false)).setAttribute('name', ms[i] + 'Price');
    t.appendChild(b.cloneNode(false)).setAttribute('name', ms[i] + 'Date');
    ul.appendChild(t);
  }

  // Set values
  b = ul.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(i = 0; t = data[i++]; ) {
    a = (t.date.split('.')[1]-1)*2;
    b[a].setAttribute('value', t.amount);
    b[a+1].setAttribute('value', t.date);
  }

  // Output/return .. whatever floats your boat.. ARRR
  return par.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
<div><h1>Salary days</h1></div>
```

You could rewrite the first part of the demo-function to use a text-based element-creation if you'd like, as you haven't specified you you wish to interact with the function.